# Drawable in View getting squashed

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, drawable, android-view

**Problem & Question:**

I currently have a view pager, with just 2 pages/views inside it, which are next to each other horizontally.

My views are custom ones which draw a two-color gradient and an image over the top of it at a low opacity/alpha value.

I'm finding that when I swipe across the screen to move from the first view/page to the second or vice-versa, the images are getting squashed. *How can I stop this from happening, and draw them normally?*

**Example:**

The **left** image shows the first view that is visible, ***pre-swipe***; the **right** image shows the two views, ***midway through swipe***.

[image: Normal view] [image: Squashed views, as I'm mid-way through swiping]

**Code:**

I have a `Drawable` variable I set earlier, `overlayImage`, that I have not done anything to other than setting opacity.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    p.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), startColor, endColor, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
    canvas.drawPaint(p);

    //Pretty sure the mistake is around these two next lines
    overlayImage.setBounds(canvas.getClipBounds());
    overlayImage.draw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: What kind of Drawable is your overlayImage? This onDraw is part of your custom view?

Comment: "overlayImage" is literally just a regular, plain Drawable; and yes this onDraw is part of my custom view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think it is in your

```
overlayImage.setBounds(canvas.getClipBounds());
```

line of code.  When you are getting the clip bounds of the left most (swiping in the right most) view, it is getting the size of the viewable area (i.e. the smaller shrinking area) and thus the image is being drawn into that shrinking space.

You probably want to be setting the bounds by the overall size of the view it is being overlayn on, not the clipped bounds.  Use instead getHeight() and getWidth() of the canvas and build up your own bounds.

I actually think that you really should setup the overlayImage bounds ONLY ONCE in your setup code.  The draw code shouldnt necessarily need to set that up at all, then when the view begins to go off screen the drawing of the overlayImage will naturally move with the rest of the drawing canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to make a `xml` in the `drawable-hdpi` folder. 
Which will contain your `shader/linear gradiant`.. (for options look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#474946"
        android:endColor="#181818"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

And then you can set the `xml` as background.. which should fix the problem i think.

(If it doesn't work try without the `android:shape="rectangle"`, that might help)